# Recursive Select using T-SQL CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a recursive select problem which I can't get to work, it feels like almost there but not necessarily.

I  have two tables where:

### Table 1 - Product List

```
List    ProductCode    SortNumber
------------------------------------
1       A              1  
1       B              2  
1       F              3  
1       G              4  
1       K              5  
2       C              1  
2       A              2  
3       B              1  
3       K              2  
3       G              3
```

### Table 2 - Product Price

```
ProductType     Client      ProductCode     Price
---------------------------------------------------
Type 1          1               A           100  
Type 1          1               A           150  
Type 1          1               B           200  
Type 1          1               B           120  
Type 1          1               F           150  
Type 2          1               A           200  
Type 2          1               A           300  
Type 2          1               B           300  
Type 2          1               F           400  
Type 2          1               G           125  
Type 2          1               G           75  
Type 1          2               A           190  
Type 1          2               A           130  
Type 1          2               A           200  
Type 1          2               B           270  
Type 1          2               B           180  
Type 1          2               F           130  
Type 2          2               A           210    
Type 2          2               A           100  
Type 2          2               B           350  
Type 2          2               F           200  
Type 2          2               G           175  
Type 2          2               G           95  
Type 2          2               K           65
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I request for Product List of 1, it will get all the max prices associated with the product code. If there's no price for Product Type 1, it will check for the max prices for Product Type 2. If there's no corresponding Type 2 price, then value is 0.

So, the desired output is that when I request for price list 1 for all clients (say here for Clients 1 & 2), the desired output should be

```
Client  ProductCode     SortNumber  PriceToDisplay
---------------------------------------------------
1       A               1           150  
1       B               2           200
1       F               3           150
1       G               4           125     (No Type 1, so we get type 2 price)
1       K               5           0       (No Type 1, 2 Price for Product K) 
2       A               1           200
2       B               2           270
2       F               3           130
2       G               4           175
2       K               5           65
```

### Tried Solution: CTE Approach

Since I was having the impression that this might be a recursive select, I have thought of using CTE. I have this query -

(**note the commented code** - *-- And pp1.ProductCode = pp2.ProductCode*)

```
Declare @List int = 1

;With ClientCTE As (
Select Distinct Client From ClientsTable
),
RecursiveSelect As (
Select p1.Client
, l.ProductCode
, l.SortOrder
, p1.Price As P1Price
, p2.Price As P2Price
, Case when p1.Price Is Null Then Case When p2.Price Is Null Then 0 Else p2.Price End
    Else p1.Price End As PriceToDisplay
From ProductList l

Left Join (
    Select Distinct pp.Client, pp.ProductCode, Max(pp.Price) As ItemPrice From ProductPrice pp
    Left Join ClientCTE c On c.Client = pp.Client
    Where pp.ProductType = 1
    Group By pp.Client, pp.ProductCode) p1 On p1.ProductCode = l.ProductCode

Left Join (
    Select Distinct pp.Client, pp.ProductCode, Max(pp.Price) As ItemPrice From ProductPrice pp
    Left Join ClientCTE c On c.Client = pp.Client
    Where pp.ProductType = 2
    Group By pp.Client, pp.ProductCode) p2 On p2.Client = p1.Client

Where pp1.Client = pp2.Client
-- And pp1.ProductCode = pp2.ProductCode **this commented code**
And l.List = 1

)

Select Distinct Client, ProductCode, SortOrder, Max(P1Price), Max(P2Price)   
From RecursiveSelect  
Group By Client, ProductCode, SortOrder
```

**Findings - CTE**

If the code is commented, it will:

- Get the prices correctly
- However, since there is no price for Product Code G and K for Type 1 in Product Price table, it will not display correctly

**Results**

```
Client  ProductCode     SortNumber  PriceToDisplay
---------------------------------------------------
1       A               1           150  
1       B               2           200
1       F               3           150
(missing G and K product codes)
2       A               1           200
2       B               2           270
2       F               3           130
2       G               4           175
2       K               5           65
```

If the code is not commented, it will:

- All product codes will appear but get the prices wrong
- The price that's being displayed is the maximum price in Price1 table, regardless of client hence

Results

```
Client  ProductCode     SortNumber  PriceToDisplay
---------------------------------------------------
1       A               1           WRONG PRICE  
1       B               2           WRONG PRICE
1       F               3           WRONG PRICE
1       G               4           WRONG PRICE
1       K               5           WRONG PRICE 
2       A               1           WRONG PRICE
2       B               2           WRONG PRICE
2       F               3           WRONG PRICE
2       G               4           WRONG PRICE
2       K               5           WRONG PRICE
```

I guess there's just one tweak that I have to do on my query but I can't pinpoint exactly where. The uncommented code returns the right values but why does it not return the missing left table values considering it is a left join?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to get the max price, you don't really need a recursive CTE

```
select  c.Client, l.ProductCode, l.SortNumber, Price = isnull(p.Price, 0)
from    ProductList l
        cross join ClientCTE c
        outer apply
        (
            -- Top 1 to return only one row per client + Pproduct Code
            select  top 1 p.Price 
            from    ProductPrice p
            where   p.Client    = c.Client
            and     p.ProductCode   = l.ProductCode
            -- Type 1 will comes before Type 2, and higher price first
            -- If there isn't any rows for Type 1, Type 2 will be selected
            -- no rows return if no rows are found
            order by p.ProductType, p.Price desc
        ) p
where   l.List  = 1
order by Client, ProductCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with join and group by

```
declare @PL table (client int, ProductCode char(1), Sort int);
insert into @pl values
       (1, 'A', 1),
       (1, 'B', 2), 
       (1, 'F', 3), 
       (1, 'G', 4), 
       (1, 'K', 5), 
       (2, 'C', 1), 
       (2, 'A', 2), 
       (3, 'B', 1), 
       (3, 'K', 2), 
       (3, 'G', 3);
--select * from @PL;
declare @PP table (ProductType varchar(10), Client int, ProductCode char(1), Price int);
insert into @PP values
       ('Type 1', 1, 'A', 100), 
       ('Type 1', 1, 'A', 150), 
       ('Type 1', 1, 'B', 200), 
       ('Type 1', 1, 'B', 120), 
       ('Type 1', 1, 'F', 150), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'A', 200), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'A', 300), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'B', 300), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'F', 400), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'G', 125), 
       ('Type 2', 1, 'G',  75), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'A', 190), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'A', 130), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'A', 200), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'B', 270), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'B', 180), 
       ('Type 1', 2, 'F', 130), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'A', 210), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'A', 100), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'B', 350), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'F', 200), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'G', 175), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'G',  95), 
       ('Type 2', 2, 'K',  65);
--select * from @pp;
select pl.client, pl.ProductCode
   --, pp1.Price as Price1, pp2.Price as Price2
     , max(isnull(pp1.Price, isnull(pp2.Price, 0))) as Price12
from @PL pl 
left join @PP pp1
  on pp1.ProductCode = pl.ProductCode 
 and pp1.Client      = pl.client
 and pp1.ProductType = 'Type 1'
 left join @PP pp2
  on pp2.ProductCode = pl.ProductCode 
 and pp2.Client      = pl.client
 and pp2.ProductType = 'Type 2'
 where pl.client in (1, 2) 
 group by pl.client, pl.ProductCode 
 order by pl.client, pl.ProductCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on requirements , here's what I would do.

1. subquery or view e.g. `vw_product_max_price`:

   `select producttype, client, productcode, max(price) as maxprice group by producttype, client, productcode`
2. query to request product list

`select MP.client, MP.productcode, PL.sortnumber, 
case MP.maxprice 
  when NULL 
  then 0 
  else MP.maxprice 
end as PriceToDisplay
from productlist PL left outer join vw_product_max_price MP on PL.productcode=MP.productcode
where MP.client = ? and MP.productcode = ?`

I havent tested this.. but the idea is to have  a list of maximum prices for each product code first.

Answer (score 0):

So I sit with a friend and worked on this. The solution that worked (tweaked from original db table name and columns) is as follows:

```
Declare @List int = 1

;With ClientCTE (BuyGroup, CustomerPriceGroup, ProductListHeaderId) As (
Select Distinct Client From ClientsTable
), 

RecursiveSelect As (
Select x.Client, x.ProductCode
, Case When Max(Type1Price) Is Null Then 
    Case When Max(Type2Price) Is Null Then 0 
    Else Max(Type2Price) End 
    Else Max(Type1Price) End 
As PriceToDisplay

From 
    (Select h.Client, h.ProductCode,
        Case When h.ProductType = 'Type1' 
            Then 
                Max(h.UnitPrice) 
            Else 
                Null 
            End As Type1Price
        , Case When h.ProductType = 'Type2' 
            Then 
                Max(h.UnitPrice) 
            Else 
                Null 
            End As Type2Price
            , h.BuyGroup, h.ConditionScale          
        From ProductPrice h
             Inner Join ClientCTE c On c.Client = h.Client
        Where           
            h.ProductType In ('Type1', 'Type2')
        And h.ProductCode In (Select ProductCode From ProductList where List = @List)           
        Group by h.Client, h.ProductCode
        ) x
        Group by Client, ProductCode
        )

select * from RecursiveSelect
```

We both figured out that on the original query, the two left joins differ only by a single criteria (which is ProductType). Once we got the raw data from the query, then we grouped and selected the price that will be displayed.

The reason for the CTE is that the original intention of the query is to get the prices for N customers. That's why the anchor query gets the list of clients and then passed on the second one. Moreover, if you would be working on X number of lists as well, you can include that in the anchor query and replace "@List" with the column on the first one.